# The function of (+=) in switch case is not working

Tags: java

I thought using `+=` the total will sum the result , but he reset everything after I insert again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Week3_Lab {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



    int product;
        int amount;

        while(true){

        System.out.print("Enter the product number(1-3): ");
        product = input.nextInt();

        if (product == -1){

            break;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the total amount of product: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();

        num(product, amount);
        }


    }


    public static int num(int product , int amount){
        double total_1 = 0;
        double total_2 = 0;
        double total_3 = 0;

        switch (product){

        case 1 :
        total_1 += amount * 2.98;
        break;

        case 2 : 
        total_2 += amount * 4.50;
        break;

        case 3 : 
        total_3 += amount * 9.98;
        break;

    }
        System.out.println("The total of product 1 is : "+ total_1);
        System.out.println("The total of product 2 is : "+ total_2);
        System.out.println("The total of product 3 is : "+ total_3);

         return product;

    }
    }
```

Comment: What value are you providing for `product` and `amount`? How is it "not working"?

Comment: I assume that you want to move the `double total_X` definitions outside of the method definition, so that they are not cleared every time.

Comment: because based on the question the outcome should be like :

Comment: Enter product number (1-3) (0 to stop) :1  , then Enter quantity sold : 200 , then keep repeat until user type 0 . then it will print the result . like product 1 cost : 200.

Comment: okay , I try again

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `total_1, total_2 and total_3` are local and not shared between method calls and therefore for each call be initialized to 0.
If you don't want this to happen define them outside of the method body.

```
static double total_1=0;
static double total_2=0;
static double total_3=0;

public static int num(int product , int amount){
    switch (product){
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Mostly right.  It would be better if they were instance variables and the logic was in a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized your `total_1` to 0, so the program is output is simply `(amount * 2.98)` as shown below:

```
total_1 = 0 + (amount * 2.98);
```

The same concept is applied for `total_2` and `total_3` as well.

Comment: I tried , but also doesn't works , seems like current way is to take out the variable out from the method.